# MySql return exists from function (exists and count)

Tags: mysql, function, count, exists

I want to check if a row exists and if it is not return a message to the user.
The following tests i made and the results i got:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `ud_fnc_DoesUserNameExist`(userName varchar(200)) RETURNS int(11)
    BEGIN

    return exists(select `Id` from `ud_tbl_User` where `userName` = userName);

    END
```

this function returns 1 even if the value does not exist.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `ud_fnc_DoesUserNameExist`(userName varchar(200)) RETURNS int(11)
    BEGIN

    return (select count(`Id`) from `ud_tbl_User` where `userName` = userName);

    END
```

this function also returns 1 even if the value does not exist.

Comment: Don't give parameters the same names as column names.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your parameter is named exactly like your column name

thus MySQL choose to interpret it as the column name and you are ending up with a `where columnname = columnname` , which is the same as `where 1 = 1` which returns always true

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `ud_fnc_DoesUserNameExist`(myUserName varchar(200)) RETURNS int(11)
    BEGIN

    return exists(select `Id` from `ud_tbl_User` where `userName` = myUserName);

    END
```